# Filter is not working if filter name contains "(" and ")" in Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm using Solr 4.0 with solnet. I'm facing issue with filter while filter name contains contains "(" and ")" .

e.g Filter name is "Test (test) Test2". 
I got an error while filtering with this type of filter.

Error is `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request`.

How to handle this type of situation? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

- - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query:

\(1\+1\)\:2

Source -

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping Special Characters